# How to create a new many to many relationship with existing records?

Tags: typescript, postgresql, many-to-many, prisma

I have a many to many relationship modelling a boxing match:

- A fight can have multiple fighters (always 2)
- A fighter can be in multiple fights

My schema looks like this:

```
model Fight {
  id            Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  fighters      FighterFights[]
}

model Fighter {
  id        Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  name      String  @unique
  fights    FighterFights[]
}

model FighterFights {
  fighter      Fighter     @relation(fields: [fighterId], references: [id])
  fighterId    Int
  fight        Fight @relation(fields: [fightId], references: [id])
  fightId      Int

  @@id([fighterId, fightId])
}
```

I want to create a new fight with 2 existing fighters. This is what I've tried:

```
const result = await prisma.fight.create({
  data: {
    fighters: {
      connect: [{ id: fighter1 }, { id: fighter2 }],
    },
  },
})
```

But I get this typescript error:

```
Type '{ id: any; }' is not assignable to type 'FighterFightsWhereUniqueInput'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'id' does not exist in type 'FighterFightsWhereUniqueInput'.
```

How should my `prisma.fight.create` function invocation look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that as follow:

```
const { PrismaClient } = require('@prisma/client')
const prisma = new PrismaClient()

const saveData = async () => {
  const fighter1 = await prisma.fighter.create({
    data: {
      name: 'Ryu',
    },
  })
  const fighter2 = await prisma.fighter.create({
    data: {
      name: 'Ken',
    },
  })

  console.log(JSON.stringify(fighter1, null, 2));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(fighter2, null, 2));

  const fight = await prisma.fight.create({
    data: {
      fighters: {
        createMany: {
          data: [
            {
              fighterId: fighter1.id,
            },
            {
              fighterId: fighter2.id,
            },
          ]
        },
      },
    },
    select: {
      id: true,
      fighters: {
        select: {
          fighter: true,
        },
      },
    },
  });

  console.log(JSON.stringify(fight, null, 2));
}

saveData()
```

It will return the following

[image]